# Sources for Milchemet Mitzvah at this time

Tags: sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, army-military-war, state-of-israel

I heard recently a certain rabbi say that "nobody disagrees that [our "war" to conquer Israel] is a milchemet mitzvah."

What sources are there, either way, for conquering Israel today being milchemet mitzvah. Does that apply to all of modern day Israel, to all nations living there?

Comment: I assume you are purposefully excluding the (nowadays highly relevant) factor of defending Jewish lives in determining which wars are Milchemet Mitzva?

Comment: @DoubleAA no actually, I'd be happy to see sources relating to that too....as long as it discusses relevance of milchemet mitzvah to fights in Israel today.

Comment: The rabbi was wrong: I disagree.

Comment: @Adám, as do I and many others I know.

Comment: Who was this rabbi? This would likely improve the question

Comment: Maybe he meant "the wars to defend Israel"? That's more likely to be undisputed

Comment: I beileve Rav Goren wrote about this in Meisiv bmilchama

Answer (score -2):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein responded in 1979 to a question from Kfar Chabad -- "you asked me to spell out all the practical guidelines on the laws of *milchemet mitzva* applicable today. I only answer practical questions as asked. Nobody's asking me, and I wouldn't know what to tell them anyhow. Our job is to pray to God and have faith, and may He send Moshiach soon."

(Need to find it again in his books, bli neder.)

Comment: Where is that teshuva?

Comment: How does this answer the question? So RMF declined to answer bc he didn't know. Is that (surprising) lacuna just an interesting historical piece of trivia?

Comment: @andrewmh20 The referenced passage in the responsum in question is here: שו"ת אגרות משה חושן משפט חלק ב סימן עח:  
הנה כמדומני שידוע דרכי לכתר"ה אשר איני ממהר להשיב אף להשואלים אותי ולדברים שלא נשאלתי לא שייך כלל שאשיב אף שהיה זה שאלה פרטית בדיני איסור והיתר וכל תשובותי אף להשואלים אותי היו רק בענינים פרטיים שנוגע להיחיד ששאל אותי ודוקא כשלא היתה פגיעה לאיזה רב, ושאלה כללית לא השבתי מעולם לא בכתב ולא בעל פה, and it seems irrelevant. His point is that it isn't a specific applicable question; but a broad general question; nothing to do with which war is a mitsva.

Comment: The closing comments in the quotation from Igrot Moshe cited in the preceding comment are extremely significant comments from Rabbi Moshe Feinstein on how to understand any of his halachic responsa. This is one of other general rules that the author mentions which assign proper context to all of his words found there.